# How to export bundled libraries in my vendor.js (CommonsChunkPlugin)?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have two `webpack 2` projects

- The 1st one, let's call it `lib1` is a library of reusable React components. In the webpack config it is exported as a library with the name `lib1`. The project lists `react` and `react-dom` as external dependencies.
- The 2nd one, let's call it `proj1` is an app that uses `lib1`. Because `lib1` is served on a cdn, it's listed as an external dependency. The project also depends on `react` and `react-dom`. Using `CommonsChunkPlugin` I generare a `vendor.js` that includes `react` and `react-dom` (and eventually other dependencies).

When I run `proj1` in the browser, the code inside `lib1` fails because it can't find `react`. The libraries are loaded in this order:

```
<script src="dist/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.com/lib1/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

I guess the issue is that `react` and `react-dom` are not exported by my `vendor.js` file.

I tried using the library option like this (int `proj1`):

```
 library: "[name]", 
 libraryTarget: "umd"
```

But it creates `window.vendor` not `window.React` and `window.ReactDOM`.

How do I do that?

---

*lib1 config*

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"), // string
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    library: "lib1",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
    }]
  },
  externals: ["react", "react-dom"],
};
```

*proj1 config*

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle : './src/index.js',
    vendor : ['react', 'react-dom']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    library: "[name]",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude:  path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
    }]
  },
  externals: ["lib1"],
  devtool: "source-map"
};
```

Comment: you should post your webpack config

Comment: I added the webpack configs